# Android marker ID in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am planning to get the marker ID and want to show some information based on marker id. I am using the following code to get marker id:

> Log.d("marker", marker.getId());

I have a seperate line where I want to associate marker id with other tasks, however, for some reason it doesn't show any values/execute that section.

> if (marker.getId().toString() == "m1") { .... }

any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not how you equate a string in java.

`marker.getId().equals("m1")` is what you want since getId is already a String you dont need to do `toString()`